# How do I get rid of the rectangle with the cross in the middle of my animation

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I misclicked and now there's a rectangle with an X in it and a triangle on my screen. How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: That object is the viewport camera. You can delete it, but at least one is required in the scene for rendering. If it's just in your way, you can hide it by selecting it and pressing H (Alt+H to bring it back).

Comment: Or you could use it, because you need that for the render, press 0 on your numberpad

Answer (score 1):

you will see three/four faint grey circle icons near the (X-Y-Z) 3d somewhere in the right middle top corner.
the icons should have a (CAMERA symbol)  under the hand symbol.
that is called toggle that should bring you back to your original view point and hide the triangle and rectangle box.
press that image.

info from this link on time { 28:20 }
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz7V0_qn1Eg
[image]